# Renaming Fontfaces

Tags: macos, fonts, rename, opentype, font-faces

How do I rename a font style in an OTF font?

I have this bug here:

[image]

I now can't select any other style except "Regular".

Answer (score 1):

I believe you may have the "Regular" version installed multiple times.  I would open FontBook in your applications folder.  Then Edit->Select All, then Resolve Duplicates.  This should turn off the duplicates.  You can also right click in on the Font in FontBook and "Reveal in Finder".  This will show you where they are located at.  I would probably delete them all, and reinstall if you can find the original files.  I just spent quite a while doing this on my own system.

Comment: nope that isn't a system problem. the font was saved wrong.

Answer (score 1):

If you can get it going, the X11 utility FontForge might be able to edit the names. It has kind of a wonky interface but it works.

http://sourceforge.net/projects/fontforge/files/